# How to delete local directory with ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have to make delete some directory and create them on local before copy to the remote. Is there anyway to delete and create locally?

Currently I'm using 'command'

```
command: rm -r directory
```

But warning shows as

```
Consider using file module with state=absent rather than running rm
```

Is there any options we can use for local folder changes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use diffrent [delegation methods](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) or use the `local_action`:

```
- local_action: file path=directory state=absent
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running this in a playbook, you can use a section of the playbook that uses a local connection to make changes on the command machine, then copies files to the remote:

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Delete local directory
      file: path=/directory state=absent

- hosts: myhosts
  tasks:
      copy: src=/directory dest=/foo/directory
```

Comment: Do I need to make a new local connection just for changing the local file?

Comment: That's how ansible knows to run it locally vs on the remote machines.  You can also use local_action as mentioned below.  The local connection is good if you have a bunch of things to do locally.

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Current Ansible (2.10) does not like `- local_action:` , instead use `delegate_to`:

```
- name: Remove directory 'dir1'
  file: 
    path: "path/to/dir1" 
    state: absent
  delegate_to: localhost
```